# How to add libraries vue in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, vue.js

I'm using laravel 5.4, with webpack and vue. I'm not sure how to add new libraries to use in vue.

For example, I run

```
npm install --save jquery vue2-select
```

What do I need to do next? I need to add:

```
Import Selectize from 'vue2-selectize'
```

or

```
Require ('vue2-selectize')
```

In the

> resources / assets / js / app.js

file or

> resources / assets / js / bootstrap.js

?

Can someone help me with the correct order to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`import` or `require` do almost same thing. But `import` is more popular.

1. `npm install --save jquery vue2-selectize` You should run this in your root folder and `npm` will place those packages in 'node_modules'. Then `import` command will look in 'node_modules' and load it to your file.
2. `import Selectize from 'vue2-selectize'` in that file where you want to use Selectize.
3. `resources / assets / js / app.js` yes, this is where your front-end app start from. In vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) you can read more about [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)
4. watch [this laracast series](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/1) and may be some other. They are easy to follow.

Comment: In my case, I discovered that I had a conflict problem. Thank you for your help!

It worked for me when I used window.Selectize = require ('vue2-selectize');